# GtkTreeView: Show all columns

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How can I show all the columns of my treeview at my application startup.
My treeview has multiple columns:

```
gtk_list_store_new (N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_INT);
```

But when I run my app, I only see the first two columns (I guess by the packing my window has the minimal size), so I had to scroll to see the rest of the columns.
My question is: How can I tell my window to resize itself to ensure all the columns of the treeview are visible?

Update1:
Using **gtk_widget_get_allocation** has no effect, still need to scroll the treeview to see the rest of the columns

```
GtkAllocation* alloc = g_new (GtkAllocation, 1);
gtk_widget_get_allocation (pAD->treeview, alloc);
gtk_window_set_size_request (GTK_WINDOW (pAD->parent), alloc->width, alloc->height);
g_free (alloc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of GTK you are using, but if you happen to be using GTK3, you might use a combination of an "allocation" object and the "gtk_window_set_default_size" function.  As an example, your program could include the following additional code.

```
GtkAllocation* alloc = g_new(GtkAllocation, 1);

/* your program code prior to displaying the window */

gtk_widget_get_allocation(list, alloc);  /* List name "list" for this example */
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), alloc->width, alloc->height);
```

See if that handles your issue.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, using **GTK3** and with 'gtk_widget_get_allocation' the issue continues. :(

Comment: Hmm.  I can't think of anything else.